# Running background services in Visual Studio Code

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I would like to run a background service like MongoDB from Visual Studio Code. I tried to run it through the task runner like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "mongod",
    "isShellCommand": false,
    "args": ["--dbpath", "data\\db"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

But this will only run it inside VS with no control to stop the server, e.g. by pressing Ctrl+C.

The normal way would be to run a cmd.exe and run the mongod command from there. But I would love to nicely integrate it into VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem by using one command with subtasks.
This will run "mongod" in a separate cmd.exe shell.
Once started (in this case minimized via **/MIN**), I can stop the MongoDB by opening the cmd windows and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to properly shutdown the database.

It would still be nicer to have the shell running inside vscode, but maybe this will come in an update someday.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "start",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "never",
"args": [
    "/MIN"
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Start MongoDB",
        "args": [
            "\"MongoDB @ localhost:27017\"",
            "mongod",
            "--dbpath",
            "${workspaceRoot}/data/db"
        ],
        "suppressTaskName": true
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a watching task like in this webpack example:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "echoCommand": false,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "args": [
                "run",
                "start",
                "--silent"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "custom",
                    "pattern": [],
                    "watching": {
                        "activeOnStart": true,
                        "beginsPattern": "webpack: bundle is now INVALID",
                        "endsPattern": "webpack: bundle is now VALID"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "isWatching": true,
            "taskName": "development"
        }
    ]
}
```

The (optional) problem Matcher watching beginsPattern and endsPattern define the console output of the watcher task start and end. The watching task can be terminated via command palette.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6209#issuecomment-218154235

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve the problem. Because I still can't control the process properly. Killing the task will only kill the mongo process, instead of shutting it down properly via a signal like ctrl+C.